A simple question Using Access values in an actor in Swift
I am sure this is a simple question, but I cant see how to solve it.
I am storing an array of my actors in an Array. I need to get access to some of its value in a .first( where:{} ) call. Here is a short example of what I want to do:
actor Counter{
    var number:Int
    
    init(number: Int) {
        self.number = number
    }
    
    func getNumber()->Int{
        return number
    }
}


var counters:[Counter] = []


func addCounter(){
    for i in 1...10 {
        let counter = Counter(number: i )
        counters.append( counter )
    }
}


func getCounter2( number:Int )->Counter?{
    let found = counters.first { counter in
        return counter.number == number //--error: Actor-isolated property 'number' can not be referenced from a nonisolated context
    }
    return found
}

Thanks for your help

This is a curious pattern; it is a little unusual to be dealing with an array of actors. Perhaps if we had a little context on the broader problem you are trying to solve, we might be able to offer better advice, perhaps with different patterns to better achieve what you are trying to do.

Actors are probably not the right tool to solve your problem. Consider this: once you fetch the mutable state of an actor from extern (you need to do this asynchronously) you receive a copy of that internal state of the actor. Now, since you have the copy, the actor's state usually continuous to change within the actor. That means, your copy becomes immediately stale, and your extern logic using the state of the actor  might potentially be flawed.

I just came up with that simple example for this question. I still would want to know if there is a simple way to use the standard swift collection calls using actors?

Nope. The standard Sequence functions expect synchronous closures, making them incompatible with code that needs to access actor-isolated properties. But it is easy enough to write your own async rendition or adopt AsyncSequence patterns. Or choose a synchronization pattern other than actors. Or minimize synchronization using value-types or immutables. It is hard to advise further without a more practical, real-life example.

You are fetching actor isolated property, and you simply cannot do that from a synchronous context. This is easily solved if you make getCounter2 an async method. Are you open to that?
func getCounter2(number: Int) async -> Counter? {
    for counter in counters {
        if await counter.number == number {
            return counter
        }
    }
    
    return nil
}

If you cannot support an asynchronous pattern like this, you may have to consider a significantly more dramatic refactoring of the problem.

just wandering if there is a way of using the standard collection calls such as .first. I use those functions such as .map, .foreach .firstindex all over my projects, and wanted to make those conform

No, the problem is that the standard Sequence API is not async. I would use the above pattern. Or, if you are doing this a lot, write your own async rendition on Sequence as outlined here. Alternatively, AsyncSequence has an async version of first, but it's silly to create an AsyncSequence from the collection just so you could use its first. But that might look like this. I would go for option 1.

I agree with rob
here's the usage of rob's change.
Task {
   addCounter()
  if let foundCounter = await getCounter2(number: 5) {
    print("Found counter with number: \(await foundCounter.number)")
  } else {
    print("No counter found with the given number.")
  }
}

